# Is this class thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have an entity class

```
    package org.demo.stack;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class ValueHolder{
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @Column
        private Long value;

        /* getters and setters... */
    }
```

a related Spring JPA Repository

```
    package org.demo.stack;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

    public interface ValueHolderRepository extends JpaRepository<ValueHolder, Long>
    {
    }
```

and a class that acts as an accumulator of some kind of values, using the repository
**(Please note that this is a simplified version of a real program)**

```
    package org.demo.stack;

    import java.util.List;

    public class ValueAccumulator{
        private ValueHolderRepository repository;
        private Long accumulator;

        public ValueAccumulator(ValueHolderRepository repository){
            this.repository = repository;
            accumulator = 0L;
        }

        public Long sumOverResults(){
            accumulator = 0L;

            List<ValueHolder> holders = repository.findAll();
            for(ValueHolder holder : holders){
                accumulator = accumulator + holder.getValue();
            }
            return accumulator;
        }
    }
```

ValueAccumulator is clearly not thread-safe. If I share the same instance across different threads and `sumOverResults` is called concurrently, the
instance variable `accumulator` is going to have a non predictable value.

I also have an adapter that looks like `ConcurrentValueAccumulator`:

```
    package org.demo.stack;

    public class ConcurrentValueAccumulator{
        private ValueHolderRepository repository;

        public Long sumOverResults(){
            ValueAccumulator oneShotAccumulator = new ValueAccumulator(repository);
            return oneShotAccumulator.sumOverResults();
        }
    }
```

Now each call to `sumOverResults` uses its own instance of `ValueAccumulator`, so no data 
are shared across threads.
Under the assumption that no `ValueEntity`s are inserted or updated during the process,
can I be 100% sure that `ConcurrentValueAccumulator` is thread-safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code provided here, You are right, If we look the class ValueAccumulator seperately, then definitely its not a thread-safe(for the obvious reason which you have provided in the question).

Now If you are using ValueAccumulator class through ConcurrentValueAccumulator, then I have following observations :

1. In the method `sumOverResults()`, everytime the new instance of `ValueAccumulator`  is created,so every thread will have its own instance, no instance of `ValueAccumulator`  is shared among threads, so there is no point of data corruption as threads are working on their own objects of `ValueAccumulator`, so there is no need of any synchronization here.
2. In the ConcurrentValueAccumulator class,

   ```
      private ValueHolderRepository repository;
   ```

   The repository is common in all the `ValueAccumulator`  instances, so at this point we can think of some thread safety because we have something which is shared among different threads(repository in our case). But in the code provided here, we are just reading the `repository`, and

> there is no create/update/write operation on repository instance

, so again there is no need of any synchronization here.

So, The code is thread-safe (provided we are doing any create/write/update operation on any shared data).